# Reset initial selected value in time_range package

Tags: flutter, dart, time, range

I am using time_range flutter package and want to use start and end time for every date. On first click it is working fine, but when I am trying to change date, previously selected start and end time is still selected.

```
import 'package:time_range/time_range.dart';

var initialRangeOpeningHours = TimeRangeResult(
TimeOfDay(hour: 09, minute: 00),
TimeOfDay(hour: 23, minute: 59),

Container(
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
child: TimeRange(
initialRange: initialRangeOpeningHours,
fromTitle: Text(
'Start Time',
style: TextStyle(
fontSize: 13, color: Colors.grey),
),
toTitle: Text(
'End Time',
style: TextStyle(
fontSize: 13, color: Colors.grey),
),
titlePadding: 20,
textStyle: TextStyle(
fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
color: Colors.black87),
activeTextStyle: TextStyle(
fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
color: Colors.white),
borderColor: Colors.black,
backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF5F5F5),
activeBackgroundColor: forIos
? BaseAppTheme.of(context).gray200 //
: BaseAppTheme.of(context)
.stepsBackground, //
firstTime: TimeOfDay(hour: 0, minute: 00),
lastTime: TimeOfDay(hour: 23, minute: 59),
timeStep: 60,
timeBlock: 60,
onFirstTimeSelected: (hour) {
setState(() {
forIos = false;
});
},
onRangeCompleted: (range) {
if (range != null) {
print('dnkjfnewkf: ${range.end.hour}');
print(
'ndjkwbfkqw: ${range.start.hour}');
setState(() {
forIos = false;
timingAddedForSelectedDates
.add(selectedDate);
});
}
}));
```

This works fine, but I want to reset this timer to its initial state without any previously selected start and end time?

Answer (score 0):

Modify the code below and see if it works

```
onRangeCompleted: (range) {
if (range != null) {
initialRangeOpeningHours = range; //add this line
print('dnkjfnewkf: ${range.end.hour}');
print(
'ndjkwbfkqw: ${range.start.hour}');
setState(() {
forIos = false;
timingAddedForSelectedDates
.add(selectedDate);
});
```